# Linq: find similar objects from two different lists

Tags: c#, linq

I've got two separate lists of custom objects. In these two separate lists, there may be some objects that are identical between the two lists, with the exception of one field ("id"). I'd like to know a smart way to query these two lists to find this overlap. I've attached some code to help clarify. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class userObj
{
    public int id;
    public DateTime BirthDate;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<userObj> list1 = new List<userObj>();
        list1.Add(new userObj()
        {
            BirthDate=DateTime.Parse("1/1/2000"),
            FirstName="John",
            LastName="Smith",
            id=0
        });
        list1.Add(new userObj()
        {
            BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2000"),
            FirstName = "Jane",
            LastName = "Doe",
            id = 1
        });
        list1.Add(new userObj()
        {
            BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("3/3/2000"),
            FirstName = "Sam",
            LastName = "Smith",
            id = 2
        });



        List<userObj> list2 = new List<userObj>();
        list2.Add(new userObj()
        {
            BirthDate =  DateTime.Parse("1/1/2000"),
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Smith",
            id = 3
        });
        list2.Add(new userObj()
        {
            BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2000"),
            FirstName = "Jane",
            LastName = "Doe",
            id = 4
        });


        List<int> similarObjectsFromTwoLists = null;
        //Would like this equal to the overlap. It could be the IDs on either side that have a "buddy" on the other side: (3,4) or (0,1) in the above case.

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you want a `List<int>`, i assume this is what you want:

```
var intersectingUser = from l1 in list1
                       join l2 in list2
                       on new     { l1.FirstName, l1.LastName, l1.BirthDate }
                       equals new { l2.FirstName, l2.LastName, l2.BirthDate }
                       select new { ID1 = l1.id, ID2 = l2.id };
foreach (var bothIDs in intersectingUser)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID in List1: {0} ID in List2: {1}", 
                     bothIDs.ID1, bothIDs.ID2);
}
```

Output:

```
ID in List1: 0 ID in List2: 3
ID in List1: 1 ID in List2: 4
```

Comment: Imho he does not want anything with the ID. He just wants identical sets without the ID in the comparison. In other words: A join with every property except the ID.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply join the lists on those 3 properties:

```
 var result = from l1 in list1
              join l2 in list2
              on new {l1.BirthDate, l1.FirstName, l1.LastName} 
                    equals new {l2.BirthDate, l2.FirstName, l2.LastName}
              select new 
              {  
                 fname = l1.FirstName, 
                 name = l1.LastName, 
                 bday = l1.BirthDate
              };
```

Instead of doing a simple join on just one property (column), two anonymous objects are created `new { prop1, prop2, ..., propN}`, on which the join is executed.
In your case we are taking all properties, except the Id, which you want to be ignored and voila:

Output:

[image]

And Tim beat me to it by a minute

Comment: Thanks to you as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your `userObj` class and use that to run a comparison between the two lists. This will be the most performant approach.

```
public class NameAndBirthdayComparer : IEqualityComparer<userObj>
{
    public bool Equals(userObj x, userObj y)
    {
        return x.FirstName == y.FirstName && x.LastName == y.LastName && x.BirthDate == y.BirthDate;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(userObj obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hash = (int)2166136261;

            hash = hash * 16777619 ^ obj.FirstName.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 16777619 ^ obj.LastName.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 16777619 ^ obj.BirthDate.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this `comparer` like this:

```
list1.Intersect(list2, new NameAndBirthdayComparer()).Select(obj => obj.id).ToList();
```

Comment: The linq approach will work just fine if you want to stick with that and your lists are of trivial size, but this approach has the advantage of having the comparison logic in a reusable place in case you need it again, and using Hash comparisons which are much faster over non-trivial list sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var similarObjectsFromTwoLists = list1.Where(x => 
            list2.Exists(y => y.BirthDate == x.BirthDate && y.FirstName == x.FirstName && y.LastName == x.LastName)
         ).ToList();
```

This is shorter, but for large list is more efficient "Intersect" or "Join":

```
  var similarObjectsFromTwoLists = 
    list1.Join(list2, x => x.GetHashCode(), y => y.GetHashCode(), (x, y) => x).ToList();
```

(suposing GetHashCode() is defined for userObj)

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = list1.Join (list2, 
                obj => new {FirstName=obj.FirstName,LastName=obj.LastName, BirthDate=obj.BirthDate},
                innObj => new {FirstName=innObj.FirstName, LastName=innObj.LastName, BirthDate=innObj.BirthDate},
                (obj, userObj) => (new {List1Id = obj.id, List2Id = userObj.id}));

foreach (var item in query)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(item.List1Id + " " + item.List2Id);
    }
```